# Question about set log_slow_verbosity='query_plan' in MariaDB ans MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a question about `set log_slow_verbosity='query_plan'`

I set `log_slow_verbosity='query_plan'` on MariaDB 10.
[image]

I check the slow log and find more detailed information such as: full_scan; Full_join; tmp_table_on_disk.

When I set set `log_slow_verbosity='query_plan'` on MySQL 5.7:

```
mysql> set session log_slow_verbosity='query_plan,innodb';
ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'log_slow_verbosity'
```

How to enable this parameter on MySQL 5.7 and get more detailed information in slow log?

Comment: What makes you think that `log_slow_verbosity` is supported by MySQL 5.7?

Comment: @YanGang       When you look closer at MariaDB ref manual, you will find you need to use SET SESSION log_slow_verbosity='query_plan,explain';  and why would you not do this in your configuration for a GLOBAL recording of this valuable information on slow queries?

Comment: @Wilson Hauck: Thank you reply! you mean is add option 'log_slow_verbosity='query_plan,explain' in my.cnf ?

Comment: The option is NOT available in MySQL 5.7.nn.

Yes, the new line should be in the MariaDB 10.0.5 or > in your my.cnf [mysqld] section a simple line of   log_slow_verbosity=query_plan,explain see this URL for details

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain-in-the-slow-query-log/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [mysql manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html) shows you what parameters are accepted, and allow you to tune your system.  It's possible this is limited to long_query_time and min_examined_row_limit, while log_slow_verbosity is specific for mariadb.

Comment: Thank you reply! I know mysql not support log_slow_verbosity. enable option log_slow_verbosity on mariadb,get more detailed information from slow.log. such as: full_scan; Full_join; tmp_table_on_disk. I want to get same detailed information from mysql. have any way？

Comment: Not with 5.7, the 8 has a "log_extra" parameter.   But, once you have a bad statement in your logs, can't you ask MySQL for an "explain" ?

Comment: 8.0.14:  `log_slow_extra`, if enabled, causes the server to write additional fields to slow query log lines that provide information about slow statements. In addition, SET lines written to the log to indicate statement timestamps now use the time from the beginning of statement execution, rather than the time at the end of execution. See The Slow Query Log.